# How to modify xml config file with grep and sed?

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep, configuration-files

In my Linux training I have an exercise  that asks for replacing a statement in `config.xml` file.

I need to replace the statement:

```xml
<app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"
```

By this one:

```xml
<app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="0.0.0.0"
```

I've started to `grep` all the existing statements in the `config.xml` file but it doesn't work:

```
Cat config.xml | grep '<app-connector port="${APP_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"'
```

also

```
Cat config.xml | grep -F '<app-connector port="${APP_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"'
```

Can you tell how to find this statement in all `config.xml` file?

How to replace it with:

```xml
<app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: Utilize an XML specific command line tool, such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) because [sed , awk, grep, and so on leads to undesired results](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/113). For example try the following _xmlstarlet_ command: `xml ed -L -u "//app-connector[@port='\${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}']/@address[. = '192.168.0.254']" -v "0.0.0.0" /some/path/to/config.xml` - This command replaces all `address` attribute values of `192.168.0.254` if their associated xml node is `<app-connector>` and if it also has a `port` attribute value of `${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/<app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"$/s/192.168.0.254/0.0.0.0/' file
```

With sed, search for the line in question using /..../ and then substitute the "192.168.0.254" with "0.0.0.0"

Comment: sorry has not worked can you help me please

Comment: What does the line look like after you run It?

Comment: nothing happens. I tried sed 's/app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="192.168.0.254"/app-connector port="${APP_CONNECTOR_PORT}" address="0.0.0.0"  config.xml on single machine the error is '  char 15: unterminated `s' command

Comment: You are missing / and ' at the end of the sed command. Just copy and paste the command as it is in the solution.